# Translate SQL to LINQ with OR statements in a JOIN

Tags: sql, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I've got a pretty basic SQL join statement that I can't seem to figure out how to make it work in LINQ.  It is using OR statements in a JOIN and I have found code online for using ANDs in a JOIN but nothing helpful for ORs in my situation.

Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM Proposals AS a
LEFT JOIN Proposal_Minions AS b
    ON a.ID = b.Proposal_ID
LEFT JOIN Users AS c
    ON (a.PI_User_ID = c.ID) OR (a.Creator_User_ID = c.ID) OR (b.User_ID = c.ID)
WHERE c.Account = 'myname'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think it's possible using LINQ.

Comment: Does it have to be LINQ? If needed (and often for better performance) you can execute raw SQL against your DBconext.

Comment: Using LINQ instead of SQL is a bad code smell. Even if possible, you should NOT use LINQ. EF or Linq to SQL are ORMs, not replacements for the SQL language. Unless your query tables and results map neatly to classes, you are better off writing a proper SQL statement.

Comment: I am new to EF and trying to learn best practices.  I thought part of the benefit of EF was removing the need to do the database work and deal directly with the entities/classes?  Is it considered best practice to do as suggested below with the text SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `where` in stead of `join`:

```
from a in Proposals
join b in Proposal_Minions on a.ID equals b.Proposal_ID
from c in Users
where a.PI_User_ID == c.ID || a.Creator_User_ID == c.ID || b.User_ID == c.ID
select new { a, b, c }
```

However, this would be the equivalent of `INNER JOIN`. You can get an outer join effect by

```
from a in Proposals
join b in Proposal_Minions on a.ID equals b.Proposal_ID into j
from pm in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { a, 
             pm,
             c = (from c in Users
                 where a.PI_User_ID == c.ID 
                    || a.Creator_User_ID == c.ID 
                    || pm.User_ID == c.ID
                 select c).FirstOrDefault()
            }
```

As you want to select the `Proposal`s only you could do

```
from a in Proposals
join b in Proposal_Minions on a.ID equals b.Proposal_ID into j
from pm in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
where Users.Any(u => a.PI_User_ID == u.ID 
                    || a.Creator_User_ID == u.ID 
                    || pm.User_ID == u.ID)
select a
```

but this is not an outer join on `Users` any more. On the other hand, an outer join on both `Users` and `Proposal_Minions` would defeat their filter purpose as all `Proposals` will be selected anyway. This is still true for the outer join on `Proposal_Minions`.

Comment: I think there is a problem here if b doesn't have an entry you won't get a result even if a.PI_User_ID = c.ID or a.Creator_User_ID = c.ID, but you would in the original sql.

Comment: @DanKaufman You're right! I think my edit will do what the SQL does.

Comment: When I run that second linq statement in linqpad it gives me an error that says Proposal_Minions does not contain a definition for User_ID...does that mean the "from pm in j.DefaultIfEmpty()" is not getting the User_ID field from the Proposal_Minions table?

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I am getting a different error now.  Unable to create a constant value of type 'User'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context. Does the select on the Users table somehow need to be directed to just the ID field?

Comment: This is an exception that may occur in linqpad only, not in VS code. Did you try that?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response...I thought I would get an email when this gets updated but I didn't...anyway...when I try it in VS I am getting a 'cannot implicitly convert type' error because I am trying to set this an an IEnumerable of my Proposal model. I tack a ToList at the end and I get the 'Cannot implicitly convert type List<AnonymousType#1> to IEnumerable<Proposal>' error.

Comment: Why do you outer join the other data if you're only interested in the `Proposal`s?

Comment: There are multiple ways that a Proposal is associated with a user and I am trying to display all Proposals associated with the logged in user.  There are the two fields in the Proposals table that could relate the Proposal to the user and then the field in the Proposal_Minions table stores people associated with Proposals.  The User table is joined because as the original post shows in the SQL statement, that's where I check the username.  So in reality there is another AND that needs to occur which is "&& b.Account == User.Identity.Name"

Comment: YES!!! Thank you!  I just add my "&& b.Account == User.Identity.Name" to the Where clause and it narrows the full list down to what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute raw sql against your DB context if needed, and map results to strong type (make sure query result matches the type) e.g.

```
IEnumerable<YourStronglyTypedTable> myResults = 
dbConext.ExecuteQuery<YourStronglyTypedTable>("Your SELECT query");
```